# Code first is keep creating a database with the fully qualified name of my context

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

This is my context class

```
public class HospitalContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }
}
```

And my connection string

```
<add name="DbContext" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
     Initial Catalog=HospitalProject;
     Integrated Security=True;" />
```

I'd like to know why when I run the application, the database name is

```
HospitalProject.Models.HospitalContext
```

instead of **HospitalProject**.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Name of connection string has to match name name of your context, in this case HospitalContext. If there is no matching connection string, Entity Framework will use default factory and reflect against your class and name database with FQN. That's how it's designed to work. In your config file there is entityFramework section that has definition for default factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming connection string to `HospitalContext`  instead of `DbContext`

Comment: It's working when I change also the datasource to .\sqlexpress. I'd like to know whether sql express and (LocalDb)\v11.0 are two different servers.